# MySql stored procedure syntax error?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql and writing the code below as part of my stored procedure:

```
  SET @label_id_configuration = 0;
  IF NOT (SELECT count(1) FROM `system_labels` WHERE  `name` = 'configuration') THEN
    SELECT @label_id_configuration := Max(`label_id`) + 1 FROM   `system_labels`;
    INSERT INTO `system_labels` (`label_id`, `name`) VALUES (@label_id_configuration, 'Configuration');
  END IF;
```

It runs fine on my local system. But on the build server, it fails. The rest of the stored procedure runs fine, which means we don't have permission, database, table existence problems.

Could anyone give me a hint to troubleshoot the error message received on the server?

```
Error on or near line 151: error in SQL script data_update.sql: @label_id_configuration:=`label_id` 6
```

Comment: why don't you try
INSERT INTO `system_labels` (`label_id`, `name`)
SELECT Max(`label_id`) + 1,
'Configuration'
FROM  `system_labels`.

Comment: also what does your if condition supposed to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

After lots of investigation with no luck. I decided to use Insert Ignore and Replace instead of the script above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's erroring, but I can see how you can eradicate the use of that variable altogether (given the code shown):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `system_labels` WHERE `name` = 'configuration') THEN
    INSERT INTO `system_labels` (`label_id`, `name`)
    SELECT Max(`label_id`) + 1, 'Configuration' FROM `system_labels`
END IF;
```